# View does not appear after adding it with addSubview

Tags: ios, swift

I created UIViewController class and its .xib file.

[image]

And with .xib file everything works well. But when I tried to add view programmatically unknown errors appeared like

```
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x6000029cbde0 h=--& v=--& UILabel:0x7f851b415bd0'eheheheheheeeeeey'.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000029aa8f0 H:[UILabel:0x7f851e118460'Name']-(16)-|   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7f851e1182f0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000029aa940 H:|-(16)-[UILabel:0x7f851e118460'Name']   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7f851e1182f0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000029aa530 H:|-(0)-[UILabel:0x7f851b415bd0'eheheheheheeeeeey']   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7f851e1182f0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000029aa260 UILabel:0x7f851b415bd0'eheheheheheeeeeey'.trailing == UIView:0x7f851e1182f0.trailing   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000029aa260 UILabel:0x7f851b415bd0'eheheheheheeeeeey'.trailing == UIView:0x7f851e1182f0.trailing   (active)>
```

This is how I add the subview. I want to put it under Category label.

```
class ArticleView: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet private weak var scrollView: UIScrollView?
    @IBOutlet private weak var nameLabel: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet private weak var categoryLabel: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet weak var contentView: UIView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let contentLabel = UILabel()
        contentLabel.text = "eheheheheheeeeeey"
        contentLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        contentLabel.contentMode = .left
        contentLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        contentLabel.alpha = 1
        contentLabel.backgroundColor = .red
        contentView?.addSubview(contentLabel)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            contentLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView!.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            contentLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView!.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            contentLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: categoryLabel!.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0)
        ])
        
    }
}
```

And along with the subview, other labels, such as Name and Category, are no longer displayed.

[image]

I'm confused and lost, would be grateful for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to disable the autoresizingmask for views you add programatically if you use Auto Layout constraints

```
contentLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

More from Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622572-translatesautoresizingmaskintoco)

> Note that the autoresizing mask constraints fully specify the view’s
> size and position; therefore, you cannot add additional constraints to
> modify this size or position without introducing conflicts. If you
> want to use Auto Layout to dynamically calculate the size and position
> of your view, you must set this property to false, and then provide a
> non ambiguous, nonconflicting set of constraints for the view.